# Autocreate stub properties for interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-generation

I've switch from VB.NET to C# several months ago, while there are a lot of features I **really** like in C#, believe it or not, there are some features that I **really** miss from VB.NET.

One of those features is whenever I implemented an interface in VB.NET the stub properties and methods were automatically added for me.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the name of the interface in the class that implements it, click 'Implement Interface' then click on either of the following two:

Implement Interface: Implements stub props and methods for you.

Implement Interface Explicitly: Implements stub props and methods for you, but also explicitly names the interface the stub is for.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use the shortkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Or you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>
:-)

Comment: Totally forgot about that shortcut, and I'm the one in my group that goes crazy with them.  Thanks Mariusz.